# How to automatically change/transit from one view to another, without pushing a button or any action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

How to automatically change/transit from one view to another, without pushing a button or any action, just after some time, say 2,3 seconds in Xcode/Objective-C, how would the code look like, and where to write it?

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution might look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create and position the subviews, if necessary
    self.subview1 = ...
    self.subview2 = ...
    self.view addSubview:self.subview1];
    self.view addSubview:self.subview2];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [self showFirstView];
}

- (void)showFirstView
{
    self.subview1.hidden = NO;
    self.subview2.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(showSecondViewView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

- (void)showSecondViewView
{
    self.subview1.hidden = YES;
    self.subview2.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: If he's talking about having it happen after 2-3 seconds he would want to use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(showSecondView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Sure, that's what my code does. The initial state (created by showFirstView) will stay for 5 seconds after the view controller appears, then secondView will appear instead.

Comment: Whoops, didn't scroll all the way over. Good call.